# Is FB using incorrect MQTT protocol?

Tags: node.js, facebook, instagram, mqtt

I'm trying to connect to FB realtime protocol, that's used in Instagram app. Application is using MQTTS v3 and it looks a little strange to me. I.e. it looks like their MQTT protocol lacks clientId, or this clientId is passed as a buffer, that is [not allowed by specifications](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/mqtt-v3.1.1.html), if I know right.

*This is correct way to connect to FBNS, missing the clientId part*
[image]

*And this is how node.js module passes clientId and correct approach by specifications*
[image]

So, am I missing something and there is a way to disable clientId completely, or I will need to go low-level and work with sockets directly? Or may be someone has other ideas how to achieve results above?

Comment: Don't use private APIs. The public APIs are documented. Use them

Answer (score 0):

that is the ID, your facebook ID encoded as __int64